# Will First Name + Last Name + Date Of Birth combination be unique enough?

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, algorithm, database-design

I need help with the algorithms/ database design for my current working on web-based application (I apologize for the long question in advance)

**Application description:**

I am building a customer check-in station (it's basically just a monitor that displays a webpage and was connected to a scanner) where customers who come into an office (similar to a library) can scan their office ID card (it has an unique bar code on it) to check-in, customer information (First name, Last name, date of birth, check-in time...) will be sent/saved onto server and the office administrator will be able to see who is in the office right now and do stuff...)

When creating ID card for a new customer, the only information needed is: first name, last name and date of birth (customer can be any ages from kids to elder) => system will generate a unique bar-code (16 digits) and print out a new ID card (with only the bar-code on it)

**Problem**:

If a customer forgot/ lost their ID card or sometimes the card is too old so the bar-code can't be scanned, customer can type in their first+last name and date of birth into the check-in station then system will search for (first name + last name + date of birth) and determine whether that customer existing and check them in. But it is possible that there is more than one person who has same name + birthday:
- system then can display all matched people to screen but how can customer know which one is them self?
- or that situation can be avoided if system would not allowing customer who has same name and dob to be saved the to database in first place. But then the customer who came "second" will be very upset that he/she can not have a card :))

***Edit:***

How do I deal with this problem, I mean this is just a office so we can not ask for SSN or driver license ... the check-in process have to be simple and quick some of them maybe a kids who don't have any ID or phone (they will come with their parents/guardians) and many of them are older people (older than 70, or even 80) they can't even type that why the "ID card - scanning idea is here to help them - all they need to do is scan their card... (I don't think they ever can remember the "security question"), SMS verify will not work (phone number may be changed, not all of customer have a phone, the carrier will be involved here (coverage, rate charge...) I don't want any of that ).

OK after read all your suggestion:

I am thinking about a **4 digit pass-code** (like 3 digits security code in the back of a credit card) - it will be printed out in the ID card with the instructions and everything, this will be different from the unique customer number (used to scan), here how it works:
- when creating a new customer ID card, system will ask for an additional 4 digits pass-code and also print it out to the card, an algorithms also will be put there to make sure that customers who have same name + dob can't have same pass-code.

In case customer can't use/lost the card, after they entering name+dob to check-in, **system only ask this 4-digit passcode if there are more than 1 matched person**, otherwise if there is only 1 person matched, system will check-in them in right on.

if they ever forgot this pass code, I mean there is nothing else they can do for them self, the receptionist will have to somehow help them, **what do you guys think, I am still open for suggestions**?

***My final solution:***

Because the cards have nothing else (of customer information) rather than the bar code (customer number) on it so the best way is to preprint (pre-made)them, have them ready in the desk to give to new customers or for card replacement purposes.

- When creating a new customer, receptionist will manually input first name + last name + dob + **phone number (optional) + email (optional) + home address** + customer number (as same as in the card that they about to give to the customer) +. submit, system will check for everything, if everything is good receptionist then give customer a new card => customer come back to check-in station and check-in.
- When customers forgot card => they will need to see the receptionist => do verification process => receptionist will check them in manually.
- When customer lost card or card is damaged => they will need to see the receptionist => do verification process => receptionist then give customer a replacement card => customer come back to check-in station and check-in.

Comment: just how big is your user-base? names+dob is definitely not "unique", but if your population is small enough, it can be.

Comment: You can add phone number too. Send code to user on registered number and verify it then do whatever want to do. Or add email id

Comment: The problem with these types of password-recovery questions is that they are public; it's too easy to guess the name, birthdate, phone number or whatever of someone whose identity you want to steal. Ask for something the customer has to make up.

Comment: @MarcB It will be distributed to several offices in different areas (cities, town), to be honest I don't even know how big the user-base but it generally will be ~50 customer check-in per day , 30% of them are new customers.

Comment: @SRJ Phone and email recovery/verify will not worked, just have to be simple and quick, many of them dont have phone and email...

Comment: Of course it is possible that two customers could have the same name and date of birth. Why not identify customers with a unique login name or email address instead. However, these are not questions that a database/application designer needs to answer alone. Your customer services team need to think through and design the customer experience and factor in both ease of access and security considerations.

Comment: @sqlvogel This is just a check-in kiosk and a scan-able ID card is what unique to identify customers, problem is when card is not working (un-scanable) or customer forgot/lost their card I need a quick way to check them in without any hassles.

Comment: If you are going to go with a natural key it MUST be on datapoints that can't ever change. Birthdate is reasonable but name is useless. What happens when somebody gets married or divorced? There may already be a person with the combination. I also would think that there is too high of a risk of collision with such a thin and brittle combination like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some rambling thoughts:

You could assign users a PIN and use that to make the account unique. Presumably to insure that it is unique you would have to assign it, you can't let them invent one. (You could let them invent one and then verify it's unique. That might be good to allow people to use numbers that have some meaning to them so they can remember them.) The big catch to this is that if the person loses his PIN, you're stuck. If the PIN is printed on the card, then if the card is damaged or worn, yes, they could type in the PIN. But if they lost the card, they might have no other record of the PIN.

You could ask for their phone number and use that as an identifier. My grocery store does that for their discount card. I think almost everyone has a phone these days. For the small number who don't, you could generate a random number that looks like a phone number but is not valid (so it won't coincidentally duplicate any real phone number), and use it like a PIN. For example if you're in the US, you could make generated numbers all start 555-555 and then make the last 4 digits be like a PIN. Then the only people who would be a problem are those who don't have a phone AND who lost their card, which should be a very small number.

Is there any information in this system that is confidential, or are people committing to spending money? I mean, if someone walked up to a kiosk and typed in the name and birth-date of his next door neighbor and accessed that person's account, would that be a problem? You haven't said what the system does. If getting into the system gives someone access to the person's medical records or bank account or transcripts of his last confession to his priest, then you have to take steps to prevent unauthorized access, you can't let just anyone come up and claim to be someone else and get in. I'm reminded of a case a few years ago where a reporter got access to records of some politician's DVD rentals. He was apparently hoping to find that he had rented a lot of vile pornography or some such that he could use to embarrass the guy, though as it turned out it was mostly westerns. My point is that even seemingly innocent information could be embarrassing to someone under the right circumstances, so you have to be careful.

How often do people have lost or damaged cards? And are there clerks available who could help someone in such cases? That is, if 99% of the time someone comes in, swipes his card, and he's in and everything is good, and the number of times that someone has a lost or damaged card is very small, you could say that in those cases they have to go to a clerk and show the damaged card, or if they say they lost their card, show identification. Then the clerk can verify whatever and give them a new card. You could have the clerk search by name and have a screen that shows birth dates and addresses, ask the customer what their birth date and address is and if it matches one, give them a new card, if not, say I'm sorry you're not on file. This is quite different from a security point of view of showing the customer the list of birth dates and addresses and letting them pick one, as a customer could, (a) type in a common or overheard name and then pick any matching entry that shows up, or even (b) use this to find the address of someone they want to harass, and then you could be liable.

Comment: thanks Jay so much for your suggestion, absolutely useful. I find that your idea "please see the receptionist" if a customer had problems with their card is the simplest and safest solution. I will add phone numbers (optional) address (required) to a customer file and in case "same name + dob" ever happened, the receptionist will ask for addres/phone in addition of name + dob for verification.

Answer (score 4):

Have each customer tell you two "security question" style data: Location of birth, favorite dish, ... These can serve as uniquifiers.

You can then prevent duplicates from being entered because in case there is a colliding registration the customer must simply chose a different question.

Comment: I edit the question, basically will add 1 more field into the customer table in the SQL that store 4 digit pass-code, so customer  with same name and same dob will have to have a unique pass code.

Answer (score 0):

On the current project I met the same way to find a customer. The project is about TV stuff, so the second level of 'sieve' is address. And I think you need to expand the customer information: a username, an email, an avatar or something easy to remember (or send a SMS with code). Also you can add user friendly behavior: if a customer cannot decide which record about him/her, the customer should go through the wizard and add needed information. Yes, it's hard to find a general evidence for all customers, but you can support several kinds of extra information.
In other words: first name, last name, and birth date aren't enough for unambiguously getting a person.

Comment: I understand your idea but this is not a user registration system kind of thing, it is just a check-in kiosk and everything need to be quick and simple, so I was thinking about a 4 digits pass-code as I modified my equation, any suggestions you may have?

Comment: @RonaldinhoLearnCoding yes, some kind of PIN code is a solution. But you should pay attention to generating these codes. It's dangerous to allow customers to choose code: probability of coincidence of four fields is very small, but exists.

Comment: I will have an algorithms to make sure that customers who have same name + dob can't have same pass-code, meanwhile other customers can have same pass-code without any problem.